# SMTP Reply method

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I am creating a WebMail client, but I have a question.
Sending mails are easy if just using *SMTPClient*, but how would I send a reply, for example if the user decides to reply to a message,
Is it just basically copy the old body and append it to the new body that I am going to send or what is the better way to reply to a message

So what I bassicly want to do is

```
MailAddress replyto = new MailAddress("reply@whosoever.something");
replyto.What? = recievedmessage ID? (wich I get from my Imap Library)
replyto.Headers["whatgoeshere"] = recievedmessage ID? (wich I get from my Imap Library)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, the reply message should do the following things (which are all convention more than anything else):

1. The replied message's `To` header should be set to the original message's `Reply-To` value, if set, otherwise to the `From` value.
2. The reply message's `Subject` header should be set to the value of the original message's `Subject` header, but with a `"Re: "` prefix (unless it already has one).
3. The reply message's `In-Reply-To` header should be set to the original message's `Message-Id` header value.
4. The reply message's `References` header should be set to the original message's `References` header value with the original message's `Message-Id` value appended to it.

That takes care of the headers. For the message *body*, that will depend on whether the message body you are replying to is in `text/plain` or `text/html` format.

Since there's no real convention for `text/html` messages, I'll explain the convention for `text/plain` replies instead.

Normally, what you do, as the author of an email client is to construct a default reply text body in the following format:

```
On ${TIMESTAMP}, ${AUTHOR_NAME} wrote:
```

followed by the original message text with each line prefixed with `"> "` (greater-than space).

Depending on the mail client, the ${TIMESTAMP} string will be formatted differently, but it'll often be more-or-less the same format as the original message's `Date` header.

The author's name, of course, is taken from the parsed email address in the `From` header.

If you are auto-generating a reply to a message, it'll probably easiest to prepend the reply text to the "quoted" original message body text (which is often referred to as top-posting), but there are other styles that some people use when replying manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences it's up to you as long as the new message is properly formatted [according to the SMTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) you're free to do what you want.  SMTP is essentially a relay agent, not a mail sevrer.

Comment: maybe I asked my question incorrectly, im updating my question